# Divide Into Monthly Installments

Tags: c#

Hi I'm trying to make Monthly Installments of a "double value"
The Problem is that the decimal values get divided too, and i don't need that happen.

**Example** :

```
List<Installments> InstallmentList {get; set;}

for (int i = 0 ; int i <= Month ; i++)
{
    double Value = 90.10 ;
    int Month = 3;


    InstallmentCost = Value / Month;
     
      InstallmentList.Add (new Installment {InstallmentCost = example.InstallmentCost}      )
}
```

Doing That i will get a list of Installments where the value will be :

1. Installment = 30.03333333333333;
2. Installment = 30.03333333333333;
3. Installment = 30.03333333333333;

But I need that the decimals do not divide and and only the last Installment gets it

**Example Of The Results that i need :**

1. Installment = 30.00;
2. Installment = 30.00;
3. Installment = 30.10;

Comment: (1) Have your loop make one less iteration. (2) Floor `InstallmentCost` down. (3) After the loop, add the last installment with the remaining value (`Value - sum of other installment values`).

Comment: First problem: that code won't compile, because `90,10` isn't a valid numeric literal - and `list` should be `List`. It's really important that when you provide code, it's the *actual code you're running*.

Comment: So, you want to round the initial values down to the nearest whole number and then just use the remaining value for the final installment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just truncate the installment which only takes the integral part (if not C# then convert to something like int and back to double would do the trick!).

I have used C#, here's the working solution:-

```
double Value = 90.10;
int Month = 3;
        
for (int i = 1; i <= Month ; i++)
{
     var installmentCost = Math.Truncate(Value / Month);
     InstallmentList.Add(new Installment {InstallmentCost = installmentCost});
}

// Extract pending balance to be adjusted, total - the sum of all installments
double pendingBalanceToAdjust = Value - InstallmentList.Sum((s) => s.InstallmentCost);

// Update to the last installment
if (pendingBalanceToAdjust > 0)
    InstallmentList.Last().InstallmentCost += pendingBalanceToAdjust;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the remainder at the start and then divide the rest into equal parts:

```
double value = 90.10;
int month = 3;

// calculate the remainder with precision 0.1
double remainder = value % (month * 0.1);
double installmentValue = (value - remainder) / month;

for (int i = 0; i < month - 1; i++)
    InstallmentList.Add(new Installment {InstallmentCost = installmentCost});
InstallmentList.Add(new Installment {InstallmentCost = installmentCost + remainder});
```

the expression `value % (month * 0.1)` effectively works out what is left over if you keep giving each of the 3 months 0.1 from the value until you can no longer carry on.

Changing the precision to 0.01 will change the outcome to: 30.03, 30.03, 30.04

Answer (score 1):

Linq approach

```
decimal value = 90.10m;
int month = 3;
List<Installment> installments = Enumerable.Range(0, month).Select(x => new Installment() { InstallmentCost = Math.Floor(value / month) }).ToList();
installments.Last().InstallmentCost += (value - installments.Sum(x => x.InstallmentCost));
```